# How to disable css Animation keyframes in opera?

Tags: css

I have created an animation using CSS3 `transform` and `animation` features. Now I want to disable the animation from displaying on Opera.

When I remove the opera specific code
(`@-o-keyframes leftright { 0% { left: -10%; } 100%{ left: 101%;}}`)
 from the css the animation doesn't disable itself on Opera.

But when I remove the default animation code (`@keyframes leftright {  0% { left: -10%; }100%{ left: 101%;}}`) it does disable itself on Opera.

I want to disable it on Opera without removing the default code.

This is the code

```
@keyframes leftright {  0% { left: -10%; }100%{ left: 101%;}}
@-moz-keyframes leftright { 0% { left: -10%; }  100%{ left: 101%;}}
@-webkit-keyframes leftright {  0% { left: -10%; }  100%{ left: 101%}}
@-o-keyframes leftright { 0% { left: -10%; } 100%{ left: 101%;}}
```

is there a way to get this thing done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before anything else, *you should **always** put the **unprefixed** keyframes **last***.

This means you should have:

```
@-moz-keyframes leftright { 0% { left: -10%; }  100%{ left: 101%;}}
@-webkit-keyframes leftright {  0% { left: -10%; }  100%{ left: 101%}}
@-o-keyframes leftright { 0% { left: -10%; } 100%{ left: 101%;}} 
@keyframes leftright {  0% { left: -10%; }100%{ left: 101%;}}
```

---

And to answer your question, the reason why what you describe happens is because *Opera supports unprefixed keyframe animations* and is going to apply them (`@keyframes leftright {  0% { left: -10%; }100%{ left: 101%;}}`) even if the Opera-specific prefixed ones (`@-o-keyframes leftright { 0% { left: -10%; } 100%{ left: 101%;}}` ) are missing .

And the easiest method to achieve what you want would probably be to [**use a selector hack**](http://browserhacks.com/#op) to target just Opera (the reason I've chosen just one that works for Opera 9.5+ is that older versions don't support keyframe animations anyway, prefixed or unprefixed) and remove the animation just for that browser after you've added it for all browsers.

For example, if you have something like `<div class='boo'></div>` in the HTML, then you need to have something like this in your CSS:

```
.boo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 5em; height: 5em;
  background: blue;
  animation: leftright 5s linear 5; /* set animation for all browsers */
}
noindex:-o-prefocus, .boo { /* remove animation just for Opera */
  animation: none;
}
```

## [*working demo*](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/IrbjA)

(check it in Opera vs other browsers)

*[Please note that my live demo is using [**-prefix-free**](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/) which adds vendor prefixes as needed via JavaScript and that in **your** code you still do need to add prefixes for WebKit animations - for more info on browser support with/ without a prefix, always check [**caniuse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) ]*

Comment: You are a Duchess! Kudos for that hack!

Comment: Why would you prevent Opera from seeing a supported animation?

Comment: @HugoGiraudel maybe it's jagging on opera. I am glad to see you here :)

Comment: @AhmadAlfy To Hugo and Tim for creating Browserhacks. ;)

Comment: The animation that I have performs partially on opera. 
noindex:-o-prefocus, .boo { /* remove animation just for Opera */
  animation: none;
}
This works superbly.. Thanks for this

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
@-moz-keyframes leftright { 0% { left: -10%; }  100%{ left: 101%;}}
@-webkit-keyframes leftright {  0% { left: -10%; }  100%{ left: 101%}}
@-o-keyframes leftright { none; }
```

Sometimes you don't need to precize the prefix for that it works.
So you need to change the value to `none`.

Comment: This has absolutely no effect. First of all, Opera supports unprefixed keyframes (see http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation ) and is going to apply `@keyframes leftright {  0% { left: -10%; }100%{ left: 101%;}}`. And even if you were to write `@-o-keyframes leftright { none; }` *after* the unprefixed keyframes, Opera does not recognize `@-o-keyframes leftright { none; }`. Just test it.

Comment: you've right so I edited my answer but this code don't work in IE.

Comment: The problem is still there. It's not the presence of `@-o-keyframes leftright { none; }` that stops the animation from happening in Opera, but the absence `@keyframes leftright {  0% { left: -10%; }100%{ left: 101%;}}` as the asker already mentioned in the question.

Comment: But the unprefixed keyfram should not be removed.. in this case adding  @-o-keyframes leftright { none; } gives nothing because opera detects the unprefixed keyframe again...